# Rails update_all equivalent for assign_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have multiple objects of a `Class Subject`

```
objects = Subject.where('condition')
```

I want to update one attribute (say `colour`) for all these objects. 
One way to do this would be the update_all method:

```
objects.update_all(colour: 'red')
```

<del>But this will trigger `N` queries.</del>

I am trying to update the attributes of all these objects and then call an import on entire bunch together

```
objects.assign_attributes(colour: 'red')
Subject.import objects
```

The problem here is that `assign_attributes` can be called on individual objects but not on the entire set of objects.

---

Is there a way to achieve a single statement that will update the attributes of all `objects` without having to loop through them explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_all` constructs a single `update subjects where condition set colour='red'` sql query and it is indeed the quickest way to update multiple records, the downfall is that it does not update `updated_at` and does not call any callbacks/validations.

If you need validations and callbacks - then there's no way around updating one by one (better with `find_in_batches` or `find_each`).

Comment: Okay. So my presumption is incorrect. Thank you for pointing that out.
But what if I had use the `import` way - is there to mass assign without saving?

Comment: @Sinstein `import` is a more efficient way of inserting lots of data (also skips callbacks), it can be used for updating with `on_duplicate_key_update` option, but if you are only updating -  `update_all` will be faster